# VBA woocomerce API "rest_missing_callback_param name"

Tags: excel, vba, api, woocommerce

I have been searching and trying to resolve it, but seems I can not figure out what might be the problem.

As per woocommerce [API documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#product-category-properties) for adding category the category name is the only required property, below is my JSON format before xmlhttp.send which seems correct to me:

Immediate window:

```
[
   {
      "name": "Automotive parts and accessories",
      "slug": "Automotive parts and accessories",
      "parent": 0,
      "display": "default"
   }
]
```

However I am receiving the error in the response:

```
{"code":"rest_missing_callback_param","message":"Missing parameter(s): name","data":{"status":400,"params":["name"]}}
```

My code is as below:

```
Public Sub woo_Post_category()

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim myurl As String
Dim Json As Object

myurl = "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"

xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "authorization", "Basic " & <SECRET_HERE> \"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json"

Dim inner As Dictionary
Set inner = New Dictionary

Dim myCollection As Collection
Set myCollection = New Collection

inner("name") = "Automotive parts and accessories"
inner("slug") = "Automotive parts and accessories"
inner("parent") = 0
inner("display") = "default"
            
myCollection.Add inner
Debug.Print ConvertToJson(myCollection, Whitespace:=3)
xmlhttp.send (ConvertToJson(myCollection, Whitespace:=3))
Debug.Print xmlhttp.responseText

end sub
```

So I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here, if someone can help, and thank you :)

Comment: The example in the docs is not wrapped in an array (`[]`) so try removing that.

Comment: @TimWilliams you are a genius! it worked perfectly when I removed the collection/array! thank you so much for your help I really do appreciate  it!